# Different public IP address when connected directly to modem and behind router

Tags: router, ip, modem, isp

I am trying to get whitelisted for my work to access an internal app from the web, but I'm getting a timeout error. Our sys admin says that I am whitelisted and should be able to access the app.

I did some troubleshooting and my public IP address while i'm connected to my router is different than my public ip address when connecting directly through the modem. (Using whatismyip.com for the public address)

Anybody know what the issue is or how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the ip address when you are connected to the router is a public ip address that does not seem right.

Comment: I used "Whatismyip.com" to find it. So yes, it was the public IP address. When I connected it direct to the modem, it provided a different IP address. Back into the router, and I was back to the original IP.

Comment: What type of internet connection (what kind of modem) do you have?

Comment: Is your modem really a modem or just a media converter?

Comment: Its a cable modem. One I bought myself because i hate renting from ISPs. I'm a pretty knowledgeable user

Comment: Does either of the two IPs work? Why can't you get both IPs whitelisted?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your specific ISP works (for that matter, you haven't even revealed what your ISP *is*), but what you describe is just how regular DHCP works.

ISPs assign IPv4 addresses to customers in various ways, but the simplest option is to *not do it* at all, and to just have a DHCP pool that each client device (CPE) takes an address lease from, with no accounting for lines or ports or subscribers. (Assuming the connection provides Ethernet emulation and doesn't require PPP or similar.)

In that situation, if you connect two different devices with different MAC addresses and they both request a DHCP lease, they will naturally receive different IP addresses. And because the lease typically lasts from a few hours to days, the DHCP server (and occassionally the client, too) will remember the lease and "resume" the same IP address. It works like that for your LAN's DHCP server, and it works like that for the ISP's WAN DHCP server.

Although it is *common* for ISPs to configure their DHCP server to remember the customer's line ID so that the line always gets the same address regardless of the device's MAC address, it is not usually the *default* way that the equipment works.